# Client.Timeout when trying to push to private gitlab registry from within docker container

Tags: docker, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab

Since I want to build different docker images for testing and production within gitlab, I decided to use docker-in-docker deployment. I followed the gitlab guide (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html). Specifically the 'Use docker-in-docker executor' section.

Here is the contents of my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - build_testing

variables:
  MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'true'
  MYSQL_USER: 'dev'
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dev'
  MYSQL_DATABASE: 'debitor_management_test'

image: docker:stable
services:
- name: docker:dind
  command: ["--insecure-registry=10.11.12.41:443"]


build_testing:
  stage: build_testing

  script:
  - docker build -t 10.11.12.41/debitor_management_testing .
  - docker push 10.11.12.41/debitor_management_testing
```

The image is built, but the push fails with the message:

```
Get https://10.11.12.41/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I am able to ping the registry and can push images on the docker host, but not from within the container. How can this be fixed?